# Can a Room mailbox automatically accept bookings made by a delegate?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I have a Room mailbox with a single delegate.

I want it so that if the delegate themselves books a meeting in this room, it automatically accepts.

Currently, the room emails them asking them to accept their own booking.

I gave the delegate owner permissions to the calendar, but they still have to approve.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Exchange server, according to my tests, you can set the delegate user as Booking Delegate of the Room Mailbox. When this user send meeting requests to Room Mailbox, the Room Mailbox will temporarily automatically accept and shows "Room has tentatively accepted this event. Your request was received and is pending approval."

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients/room-mailboxes?view=exchserver-2019#change-how-a-room-mailbox-handles-meeting-requests

Hope this can be useful.

Comment: This is still tentative and asking for approval. Could it just accept it without the need for any approval at all?

Comment: I haven't found any workarounds which could accept it without the need for any approval at all. I'm afraid this might be not  avhieveable.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you also need to put the Delegate into -BookInPolicy.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-calendarprocessing?view=exchange-ps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).